# Component Metadata not being stored in Custom_Meta table

Tags: 2011, broker, metadata

I have 2 groups of components in 2 folders, both are not linked to any page, they are just standalone components, components in folder A are available in broker database and components in folder B are not in Broker db. I could not find any difference of components of folder A and folder B. I right click and publish the component, If i check what get published I see no items, each component has "Tile" and "Summary" as shown in image blow, I expect this metadata information should be stored in "Custom_Meta" table of broker database,

How can i store this information in database?

[image]

my storage file has following lines

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="Sql" dialect="MSSQL" defaultStorage="true" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="xyz" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="xyz" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_broker" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="xyz" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="xyz" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="File" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="C:\inetpub\my application" />
        </Storage>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="Sql" cached="false"> <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="File"/> <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="File"/>
```

Only pages and binary would be stored on file system  and all other things should go to database.

**Update**
just found components in folder A are linked to a component template but components in folder B are not linked to any component template. trying to create a component template for components in folder B.
I am able to link components to a template and that template is used by a page but when I publish a page I see success in logs but logs does not display any component being published.

Comment: How do you publish this component? Rightclick -> Publish on the component itself or do you publish the page? If you publish the component itself, it has to be linked to a dynamic CT. (Check what gets published by clicking on the 'Show items to publish' button in the Publish dialog).

Comment: Are there any errors in the cd_deployer log? If you set logging to DEBUG, you'll see exactly what happens. :)

Comment: Question updated for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly configure the cd_storage_conf.xml configuration file of the deployer web application (assuming you use the web application deployer and not the windows service).

This file is normally located in the bin/config folder of your web application. Could you post the contents of this file (leave out the comments and change the username/password/servername of the database nodes obviously)?

To store items in the database the default storage id of your itemtypes node should be set to point to the database store:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
```

[here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-19D0779D-3AA1-42EA-A684-9E21B33D823B.xml&docid=GUID-19D0779D-3AA1-42EA-A684-9E21B33D823B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-19D0779D-3AA1-42EA-A684-9E21B33D823B) is a link to the Tridion 2013SP1 content delivery deployer setup documentation from SDL (login required!).

Comment: <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="Sql" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="File"/>
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="File"/>

Comment: I have another folder with component and same metadata structure and they are available in broker database.

Comment: fixed and raised another question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/rendering-10-000-components-on-page-page-loading-is-very-slow